# VBA calculate the school year from the date of birth and current year - Except when the calendar year changes from December to January

Tags: vba

Hope someone can help with this.  I have an access 2010 DB. I want to calculate the current school year for a pupil.  To do this I have the date of birth on the form and a blank bound text box called "NCY"

The following doesn't take into account when the year changes from December to January, it changes the school year when I don't want it to change it until September (School year runs September to August)

```
Private Sub yearGroup_GotFocus()

Dim nowDate As Date
Dim dob As Date
Dim dobMonth As Integer
Dim dobYear As Integer
Dim NCY As Integer

nowDate = Date
nowYear = year(nowDate)
dob = Me.dateOfBirth
dobMonth = Month(dob)
dobYear = year(dob)
NCY = nowYear - dobYear


If dobMonth > 8 Then

      Me.yearGroup.Value = NCY - 6

Else
      Me.yearGroup.Value = NCY - 5
End If

End Sub
```

In English I want something along the lines of;

If the current month of current year is >8 then increase the NCY by 1
unless the current year has changed by 1 and the month in that year is <9

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Could you be more specific about how your current code is failing?  What is an input that provides the wrong output, and what should that output be?  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41961010/edit) to add more detail?  Thanks!

Comment: `NCY - 6 - if(month(nowDate))<=9,-1,0)` if I follow... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardcoded the DOB on this one because I was practicing in Excel.  This assumes the ch8ild is in grade 1 when he is 6 years old before August.  Mostly in the USA we start Kindergarten at age five, and grade 1 at age 6.  You can adjust accordingly.

```
Private Sub yearGroup_GotFocus2()

Dim nowDate As Date
Dim dob As Date
Dim dobMonth As Integer
Dim dobYear As Integer
Dim NCY As Integer
Dim currentlyInSchool As Boolean
Dim schoolYear As Long
Dim schoolGrade As Long


nowDate = Date
nowYear = Year(nowDate)
dob = DateValue("Feb 15, 2000")
dobMonth = Month(dob)
dobYear = Year(dob)
NCY = nowYear - dobYear
abc = 123

'   First find out the current school year.
'   School year runs from August to May
    If Month(nowDate) <= 5 Then
      schoolYear = Year(nowDate) - 1
    Else
      schoolYear = Year(nowDate)
    End If

    Debug.Print "School year:   " & schoolYear & "/" & Mid(CStr(schoolYear + 1), 3, 2)

If Month(dob) < 8 Then
 schoolGrade = 1
Else
 schoolGrade = 0
End If

schoolGrade = schoolGrade + (schoolYear - (Year(dob) + 5))
Debug.Print "Pupil Grade:  " & schoolGrade
End Sub
```